# Spring boot service calls will not run through HTTP Proxy (Fiddler)

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, fiddler

My code is a service that makes external rest/soap calls.  I want to be able to see these calls in a network monitoring tool such as Fiddler.

The technologies I'm using are:
IDE - Intellij
Framework - Spring Boot
Build - Maven
Jdk - 1.8.0_151

Most articles online tell me to set the VM options in the configuration to

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8888
-Dhttp.proxySet=true
```

I've also tried the variation

```
-DproxySet=true 
-DproxyHost=127.0.0.1 
-DproxyPort=8888
```

I've added the above in the VM options for the configuration and also the VM options under
Help -> Custom VM Options

I've tried modifying the Intellij proxy settings under
File -> Appearance and Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy
I've tried adding proxy settings directly in code such as:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");
```

I've tried the above in every place conceivable.
I've setup a keystore for https traffic as well following a guide such as  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2017/04/26/capture-java-vm-traffic-using-fiddler/

I've also tried modifying the Maven Settings and adding the proxy there as well

```
   <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>
            <port>8888</port> 
        </proxy>
   </proxies>
```

I haven't touched any fiddler settings other than enabling https decrypting.

I'm quite new at developing in a Java environment but it feels like I'm doing what I'm supposed to be doing to see my services http calls where are the possible places that could be overriding the settings I add?

Comment: Do you get any incomming connections on your proxy?

Comment: Yes, I use fiddler everyday for everything else.  I can see the service calls I make to my application, but I cannot see any service calls my application makes to other applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies within the framework we're using to actually make the service call.  We are using a JaxRs client.  I tried with a standard HttpUrlConnection and I was able to get things working properly